# API Manager 2.6.0 won't start -- can't find carbon.xml file, but install went fine

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Windows Server 2016
Installed Java JDK 1.8.0_192, and set JAVA_HOME path as directed
Download and install of WSO2 API manager 2.6.0 was all good...

when trying to start wso2server.bat, 
briefly get the following error message on screen:

Error: Could not find or load main class
Manager\2.6.0\bin..\repository\conf\carbon.xml

From folder structures, carbon.xml file appears to be in proper place:
C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\2.6.0\repository\conf

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Spaces in the installed path could be the issue. Try to install to a different location without spaces and check.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment from Rans, I simplified the path with latest install to the following:
C:\WSO2\APImgr\v260\bin

I also ran the WSO2server.bat from command line, while in the bin folder, and it completes the startup tasks, and now appears to be running fine.

Thanks!